# Repeating Login Prompts when deploying reports using Visual Studio 2012 BIDS

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am running SharePoint 2013 integrated with SQL Server 2012 and SSRS but I've been having problems trying to deploy my reports from Visual Studio 2012 BIDS.  Whenever I enter in my 
login credentials it just pops up and ask me for them once again.  I've looked in the log files and here is what I see:

> SPRequest.OpenWeb: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName=
>   ,bstrUrl=https://client.test.com/TestClient/ReportService2006.asmx
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_EnableMinimalDownload()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.P...

However, it doesn't make sense to me because with the same account I have tested manually deploying the reports by uploading them to their document library using the SharePoint web interface and everything works just fine.

I am using forms and Windows authentication together and I have tried using both a forms and a Windows account to deploy the reports and neither one works.  Also, I have checked the well known DisableLoopBackCheck keys and confirmed that it is not the issue.

Comment: where can i find this log file?

Comment: @breceivemail You can find them at C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Logs where "15" is the version number for your edition of SharePoint.  An easier way to view the logs though would be to use the SharePoint ULS Viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I extended my web application with just a Windows Authentication site (https://clientmanage.test.com) and now I deploy to that address instead of the main https://client.test.com).  This way I can still allow Windows and Forms Authentication from a single address (client.test.com) while at the same time I can deploy reports, data sources, etc. from Visual Studio using another address (clientmanage.test.com).